# iOS How to create parallax effect in scroll view for image Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, parallax

**How can I create a parallax effect for my image**?
I use scroll view. I found tutorial only for table view.
*Is it possible to create such an effect for the image?*
**UPDATE code :**

```
@IBOutlet weak var topConstrain: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        topConstrain.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
    else {
        topConstrain.constant = 0
    }
}
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: You can take a look following link https://gist.github.com/valeriomazzeo/48e09cbed4ab4e09b381f595c6b4711c

Comment: It's very old code, i have 46 errors :D

Comment: You can do it using UIScrollView. In didScroll get the content offset, make a ratio and apply that ratio as CGAffineTransform(translationX: and CGAffineTransform(scaleX to your imageView .

Comment: Do you want to scroll background image with foreground text .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll image with some foregroundScroll ,you have to take two scrollview's 
1)ImageScrollview
2)Foregroundscrollview
 ,add imageview to backgroundscrollview and call scrollViewDidScroll delegate.

```
   class ParallarXController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {
         @IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!
         @IBOutlet weak var foregroundScrollView: UIScrollView!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
               super.viewDidLoad()
               let rearImg = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named: "readArticalBGimage"))
                    rearImg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.imageScrollView.frame.width), height: self.view.bounds.height+110)
                    imageScrollView.contentSize  = CGSize.init(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height+100)
                    rearImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                    imageScrollView.addSubview(rearImg)

                }


     func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
                    let foregroundScrollviewHeight = foregroundScrollView.contentSize.height - foregroundScrollView.bounds.height
                    let percentageScroll = foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y / foregroundScrollviewHeight
                    let backgroundScrollViewHeight = imageScrollView.contentSize.height - imageScrollView.bounds.height
                    imageScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: backgroundScrollViewHeight * percentageScroll)
      }
   }
```